# How can I set Apache to serve files as text?

Tags: apache-1.3

What configuration is required to make Apache serve all files as text files in the browser window? For example if I have a file `program.c`, how can I make Apache serve it as plain text in the browser window rather than as a download?

I'm using Apache 1.3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this to **force the data type** of all files, e.g. for a specific location:

```
<Location "/programfiles">
    ForceType text/plain
</Location>
```

So, no matter what's in there, even `.php` files, they're treated as plain text and shown to the browser instead of being download or even executed on the server side.

For more info see the [**mod_mime reference page for ForceType**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html#forcetype).

Comment: +1 Good call. I added a link to the Apache reference for this.

Answer (score 14):

You want ALL files to go over as plain text??  Or do you have a subset of filetypes you want to send as plain text?  Not sure if there's a way to set *everything* to go over as plain text.

For certain file types you would just add directives to your `/etc/mime.types` file, site-wide Apache config, or local `.htaccess` file

```
AddType text/plain .c
AddType text/plain .h
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it will be useful for reference.

Comment: This solved it for me but, in my case, I had to also add the following "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8"

Answer (score 2):

Create `.htaccess` in target directory (applies to it's subfolders too):

```
<Files "\.(html|c|php)$">
    ForceType text/plain
</Files>
```

To apply to all extensions, use asterisk `*`:

```
<Files "*">
...
```